# Django raise forms.ValiadationError not displaying

Tags: python, django

I have a django login form and when I click sign it, it is supposed to show some errors if something is wrong, however it doesn't appear in the html if I do print `form.errors` it appears in the console, here is an example : `<ul class="errorlist"><li>username<ul class="errorlist"><li>User does not exist!</li></ul></li></ul>` and then instantly after that it displays`"POST /signin HTTP/1.1"` in the console. I was wondering, why does it print the HTML in the console if I ask it to and not display it on screen. I tried `{{form.errors}}` and `{{form.non_field_errors}}`.
View Code:

```
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/tickets/createticket')    
    stuff = {'form': LoginForm}
    print form.errors
    return render_to_response('tickets/login.html', stuff, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Html:

```
{%load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'tickets/signin.css' %}"/>
<h1>Please Sign in</h1>
<form method="POST" id="signin">
{% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
</form>
```

Comment: Show your view and html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here. You are passing form class:

```
stuff = {'form': LoginForm}
```

You should pass the form instance which you tried to validate:

```
stuff = {'form': form}
```